# Gravity forms civi plugin from Civivip.com. I'd like to resurrect - does anyone have a copy?

Tags: wordpress, forms

It seems the website (civivip.com) no longer exists, nor has there been any facebook or twitter activity for years.
Might anyone know the developer and how to contact?

What are the ethics of obtaining the original code & resurrecting as free extension?

With Caldera phasing out we are getting desparate!

Thanks all

Comment: What kind of forms are you building? Do they use transactions?

Comment: Contribution forms Stripe and Paypal

Comment: I don't think that their Gravity Forms integration will help with that - pretty sure it didn't do contributions.

Comment: Reckon you're right - I just thought it would provide a start. Also we have a few simple forms.

Comment: Does your site use ACF Pro? If so, you can use CiviCRM Profile Sync for forms that don't require contributions. Docs here: https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/blob/master/docs/ACFE.md

Comment: Thanks very much Christian. The Woocommerce plugin looks good too.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but I have their plugin that they made for Syncing GiveWP contributions.
However it's not been updated for a while and I am not sure if it even works anymore with the updated GiveWP and CiviCRM.